# carto.js + Highchart.js

Tags: carto, infowindow, chart

Has anyone some examples of  info-windows showing highcharts.js in it ??

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YRNHP/3/) but using carto data . I also found  [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/cfc0f9b04459b34ecad0) but I need an interactive chart .

Comment: Hey @Pablo Gallego Cadabón I have just updated my answer. It can be done. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** Feb. 23 2017

It looks like it can be done. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/4946cb672b1cd00650b6246b0524e57f/) you have a working example. Basically, you have to:

- set the sublayer interactivity pointing to the fields you want to show on the chart,
- store the data of the selected feature in variables,
- use `chart` method from Highchart.js library (be careful with the function scope!) using the variables you have just created.

This is the result (instead of a popup, I choose a fix box):

[image]

Comment: Hey @PabloGallegoCadabón if you think this answer solves your issue, please mark it as solved.

Comment: Great ! That's exactly what I was looking for! thanks Ramiro!